# Restrict single and double quotes in textbox in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to restrict sinqles qoutes and double quotes to enter to a Textbox in Asp.net. How can i achieve it? How can i validate the textbox?

Comment: What is your reason for this? Is it related to issues when inserting into SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a `RegularExpressionValidator`and set the `ValidationExpression` ='^[^\"]*$' to restrict quotes input

Answer (score 3):

Do you use AjaxControlToolkit? if so, then use this.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" Width="100px" />
<cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender FilterMode="InvalidChars" ID="ftbe_TextBox1" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="TextBox1" InvalidChars="&quot;'" />
```

Where: cc1 is the TagName for AjaxControlToolkit

if not, do it manually

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" Width="100px" onkeypress="return restrictQuotes(event);" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function restrictQuotes(evt) {
        var keyCode = evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        return (keyCode != '"'.charCodeAt() && keyCode != "'".charCodeAt());
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `javascript` to do real-time validation with the textboxes `onchange` event.  Then you can use the `string.contains()` method on the `server-side` for `server-side` validation.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fixit() {
  var numberOfElements = document.theForm.elements.length;
  for (x=0; x<numberOfElements; x++)  {
  // replace all the single, double quotes:
    var curElement = window.document.theForm.elements[x];
    curElement.value = curElement.value.replace(/\'/g, "&#39;");
    curElement.value = curElement.value.replace(/\"/g, "&#34;");
  }
  return true;
}
</script>
```

Then in the form you would write this

```
<form name='theForm' onSubmit='return fixit()'...
```

This code would cycle all the elements. If you want to validate a single element you could prevent the user from writing those characters

in the textbox you could do this:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" onkeypress="return fix(event);">
```

In javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fix(e) 
{
   if(e.charCode == 34|| e.charCode == 39)
   {
     return false;
   }
   return true;
}
</script>
```

The last part prevents users from writing quotes and double quotes.